# Pre-launch report "Native crash"

Tags: android, crash

Google Play Console Pre-launch report states a crash with my app running on Google Pixel 2 (arm) (virtual) (no issues with the others). The Android Version is Android 13 (SDK 33). When watching the replay, I see no issue and the app doesn't crash.

Here the info provided.

Native crash of com.xxx
backtrace:
#00  pc 0x0000000000364a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+2536)
#01  pc 0x0000000000418cd4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::InitializeClass(art::Thread*, art::Handleart::mirror::Class, bool, bool)+3636)
#02  pc 0x00000000004241f8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (NterpGetClassOrAllocateObject+2860)
#03  pc 0x000000000020f480  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_get_class_or_allocate_object+48)
#04  pc 0x00000000002019d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_op_new_instance+80)
#05  pc 0x000000000020a254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#06  pc 0x0000000000202db0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat

Can someone explain to me where the error is and how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.